# What to choose to store just one integer? Sqlite? or Text file?

Tags: php, web-services, sqlite, text-files

I've build a small web-service in PHP. I want to control the number of calls to a specific API method.

I thought at first of using a text file, because it's just an integer. But after taking a good look at SQLite it seemed much more convenient.
So the code is just: get the "counter" from SQLite and increment it when that method is called, then store it back on SQLite db.

Is this a right way of doing it? Would it be simpler and more scalable to just use a file or... maybe something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a real database both a textfile, and a SQLite DB will have locking issues where if the file(s) is currently open and a new request to open it happens the second request will error out.  Use a real DB like MySQL, MSSQL, or whatever is available.

Comment: SQLite definitely copes with multiple processes/threads/handles to the same DB.

Comment: But they are still just files.  A full DBMS like MySQL is MUCH MUCH better at handling 1000 simultaneous writes.

Comment: Where do you think MySQL stores it's data? In a magical treasure box?

Comment: But you do have a point, SQLite apparently locks the whole DB instead of the record: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/04/12/442615.aspx. Warrants more research.

Answer (score 5):

a third possibility: [memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/). it's compatible with [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/), but stores it's key-value store to a BDB file.  it not only has read-write commands, but also atomic increment/decrement for numeric values.

one more alternative would be to write a 'counter server'. an independent process that gets 'read' and 'increment' commands over a socket. the advantage is that it's really easy to do 'atomic' increments.  it stores it's counter(s) on a simple file, without concurrency problems since there's never more than one server.

it should be easy to write in less than a hundred lines of C.  just a tight loop processing one command at a time, flushing to disk every few seconds.  since the processing is so simple, the latency is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

A database would typically scale better than the filesystem, but you are going to need to be careful and use appropriate locks with either mechanism.

Comment: SQL database just for storing one integer? I'm actually shocked your answer is upvoted so much, this is sad state of software development.

Comment: @lubos hasko: I am merely stating the facts. The poster is talking about a web service; will the filesystem scale to thousands of calls to a single file?

Comment: Flat files will scale just like SQLite because SQLite *are* flatfiles. Only that you need special library to read them or write into them.

Comment: @lubos hasko: what mythical properties must have a DB file to not be 'flat'? SQLite DBs are BTrees, on top of a a inner 'page' structure, and a complex strata of loaded/cached/dirty/disk/commited.

Answer (score 2):

Of course use flat file.

- It will be right thing to do
- Extremely simple
- No dependency on third-party library
- You will be able to view or update counter with just plain Notepad.
- Faster than SQLite (no SQL parsing, no other overhead)
- and as scalable as SQLite (SQLite are just more complex flat files)

*If you will ever need something as fast as possible, you will have to make persistent process in memory to eliminate I/O bottleneck. But please... just don't use SQL database to store single integer.*

Comment: you make no mention of how to handle locking and potentially transactions... locking is key to get this thing to working in a reliable way.

Comment: Oh, and what do you think, how SQLite handles locking? It either opens file in read-only mode or exclusive read-write mode.... there is no magic.

Comment: You are missing the point. You either open file in shared read mode or exclusive read-write mode. That's how SQLite internally operates as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [shared memory](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) to hold the counter, and [locking](http://se.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php) to ensure safe increments.

Answer (score 0):

According to SQLite it can handle sites that go up to "100K [*sic*] hits/day". If you're going over that, you may need to investigate a more robust database like MySQL. But if you're writing 100k records to the database every day for one website I think something is wrong with what you're doing, based on your example. This really sounds like a job for caching. Which I know nothing about in PHP, sorry.

They have this to say about files vs. SQLite: "Many programs use fopen(), fread(), and fwrite() to create and manage files of data in home-grown formats. SQLite works particularly well as a replacement for these ad hoc data files." ([source](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html))